# Using the 'in' operand to check if string contains a keyword with and without whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wrote this code to sort out a new taglist, by checking if a description(string) contains a specific keyword.

For example

```
tagslist=['LED_AuraSync', 'LED_ARGB', 'LED_RGB', 'LED_Blue...',]
description=('Arctic Freezer 50 Dual Tower ARGB Heatsink ...')

tagged=[]
for tags in tagslist:
    splitted=tags.split('_')[1]
    if (splitted) in description:
        tagged.append(splitted)

print(tagged)
```

This will add ARGB and RGB to the 'tagged' list as well, which is wrong as the description only in reality contains ARGB only, however if i add whitespace before and after the 'splitted' variable with the 'in' operand, it works correctly

```
if (' '+splitted+' ') in description:
```

But I don't understand why it works, could someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL; DR

```py
tagslist = [
    "LED_AuraSync",
    "LED_ARGB",
    "LED_RGB",
    "LED_Blue...",
]
description = "Arctic Freezer 50 Dual Tower ARGB Heatsink ...".split()

tagged = [
    splitted for tag in tagslist if (splitted := tag.split("_")[1]) in description
]

print(tagged)
```

As a list comprehenshion

### Why it does not work in the first place? (Why it works later)

The key part to this answer is that `in` operator matches any part in the string, doesn't matter if you want to match **word by word**.
So, `"RGB" in "ARGB"` would have been computed to `True`.

But if you split the description by whitespace (turns it into a list of strings), and use the `in` operator, it would work because it's compareing each string in the list and see if they are the **same** as the given, instead of **matching** a substring from it.

By using `" " + splitted + " " in description`, you essentially matched `splitted` with whitespace around it, so when it is the iteration of `"RGB"`, it is actually investivating if `" RGB "` is in the description. And it is not, so it is not appended to the list.

### A little more into the comprehenshion

I'm guessing here that op does not have much experience with python, so I will give a little explaination here :)

That list comprehenshion,

```py
tagged = [
    splitted for tag in tagslist if (splitted := tag.split("_")[1]) in description
]
```

is essentially (not fully) equvilent to the following:

```py
tagged = []
for tag in tagslist:
  splitted = tag.split("_")
  if splitted in description:
    tagged.append(splitted)
```

where the warlus operator `:=` assigned `tag.split("_")[1]` to splitted in the comprehension to make it compute only once.

> An alternative way to write it would be
>
> ```py
> tagged = [
>    tag.split("_")[1]
>    for tag in tagslist 
>    if tag.split("_")[1] in description
> ]
> ```
>
> but it will compute `tag.split("_")[1]` twice.

Comment: I don't understand how the part before "Why it does not work in the first place?" contributes to answering the question.

Comment: This is a neat solution and explanation.
Another issue is i just realized, i have to sanitize the keywords first because if the 
description has a coma in the code will be checking the word and the coma as a whole

Comment: I feel like this answer buries the lede by putting not emphasizing that `description` is split. All the list comprehension and walrus operator stuff is noise. The only change the OP's code needed was `description.split()`.